# Xcode preview and console too slow or not working

Tags: xcode, swift-playground, xcode14

I had just recently downloaded xcode and everytime I write code and come to an error, I would fix the error but the console and preview do not update. It down not change the error live will not rerun my code even though I have it on Auto run.

I would have to close the whole app. Re-open the file that I am working on, then wait about a min before xcode runs through my code and sees that there is no error and show the preview outputs that should had been there.

I am using a 2017 MacBookPro, 16gm Memory, Ventura 13.4 macOS

Comment: CTRL-Alt-P to pause/run the preview. Note that preview need a hidden iOS  simulator to run on the Mac which make starting a preview take time the first time. Also error in the app code may prevent preview to work. Compiling is done each time you modify code.